# Shiny datatable row id changes when sorting table

Tags: r, sorting, shiny, dt

I have a shiny app in which a datatable `table` using the `nc` dataset is rendered. I would like to select the row with row-id equal to 2 when clicking an `actionButton()`, which I achieve as follows:

```
dataTableProxy("table") %>%
      # deselect any previously selected row
      selectRows(NULL) %>%
      # select row with id 2
      selectRows(which(input$table_rows_all == 2))
```

[image]

This works perfectly fine, but the behaviour seemingly turns random when sorting the table. For example, when sorting on the column `PERIMETER`, a click on the button highlights the row with id == 15, which is the 5th row in the sorted table whereas I would expect it to still select the row with id == 2, in this case the Alleghany county. I also added a `verbatimTextOutput()` to clearly show that the row with id == 15 is selected. The same random behaviour applies when sorting based on other columns.

[image]

The behaviour I want to achieve is the button to *always select the row with id 2*, irrespective of its position when the table is sorted. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is a minimal reproducible example of my code:

```
# Load packages ----
library(shiny)
library(sf)

# User interface ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width=4,
      style = "height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto; margin: 0px;",
      actionButton("select",
                 label="Select row with id = 2")
    ),
    mainPanel(width=8,
              style = "margin: 0px;",
              "Table",
               tags$style('#table :is(th, td) {padding: 4px;}'),
               div(dataTableOutput(outputId = "table"), 
                   style = "height: calc(47vh); font-size: 75%; width: 100%;"),
              br(),
              br(),
              verbatimTextOutput('printfield')
    )
  )
)

# Server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>%
    st_transform(crs=4326)
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({DT::datatable(st_drop_geometry(nc),
                                                     selection= "single",
                                                     options = list(scrollX = TRUE,
                                                                    scrollY = "47vh",
                                                                    dom = 't',
                                                                    paging = FALSE))})
  observeEvent(input$table_rows_selected, {
    output$printfield <- renderPrint({input$table_rows_selected})
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$select, {
    if (input$select%%2==1) {
    dataTableProxy("table") %>%
      selectRows(NULL) %>%
      selectRows(which(input$table_rows_all == 2))
    }else{
      dataTableProxy("table") %>%
        selectRows(NULL)
    }
  })

}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### Edit: solution found

It turns out the solution to my question is very simple. Instead of using `selectRows(which(input$table_rows_all == 2))` I should have simply used  `selectRows(2)` as such:

```
  dataTableProxy("table") %>%
    selectRows(NULL) %>%
    selectRows(2)
```

For some reason the automatically generated row indices change upon calling `input$table_rows_all` which led to seemingly random behaviour when the table was sorted.

Comment: Looks like you're highlighting by an automatically generated line number - would it be better to add a serial row ID as a hidden column so you can select by that?

Comment: Yes, ideally I would use the ```CNTY_ID``` as the unique identifier of each row. However, I don't know how this can be achieved.

Comment: It's possible but only if you use `server = FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a solution with the **Select** extension and the `rowId` option. But the **Select** extension requires `server = FALSE`.

```r
library(DT)
library(shiny)

rowNames = TRUE # whether to show row names
colIndex <- as.integer(rowNames)

dat = iris[1:5,]

dat[["rowId"]] <- paste0("row-", seq_len(nrow(dat)))

callback <- JS(
  '$("#btn").on("click", function() {',
  '  var index = $(nbr).val();',
  '  var rowId = "#row-" + index;',
  '  table.row(rowId).select();',
  '});'
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("nbr", "Choose a row", value = 1, min = 1, max= 5),
      br(),
      actionButton("btn", "Select this row")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("dtable")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      dat,
      rownames = rowNames,
      extensions = "Select",
      selection = "none",
      callback = callback,
      options = list(
        rowId = JS(sprintf("function(data){return data[%d];}",
                          ncol(dat)-1L+colIndex)),
        columnDefs = list(
          list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(dat)-1L+colIndex),
          list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")
        ),
        select = TRUE
      )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, Stéphane. Your solution works just fine, but I have found a much simpler solution that I have added to my own question.